# Oracle Weblogic IPv6 with Oracle database on IPv4

Tags: ip, oracle-database, weblogic

I have one `weblogic` application currently working on IPv4 and `jdbc` connection to database is on IPv4.

Since my machine has an additional Ethernet port that supports IPv6, I am thinking to add an additional entry in `DNS AAAA` and try to clear my doubt.

If an HTTP hit comes via IPv6 internally, `weblogic` will bind database on IPv4 and take the required results and give these results back to client browser on IPv6.

- Will the above method work?
- What are the other factors I should consider?
- Is a dual stack mandatory other than IPv6 only?

Answer (score 0):

Yes dual stack is mandatory in that case, because Oracle Database does not support ipv6.

see link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e10105/host.htm#ASADM648

You will need to configure network channels in order to separate the ipv4 from ipv6  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13701/network.htm#CNFGD179

Its a complicated process that has a difficulty factor depending on whatever you have deployed in weblogic. Personally i am not sure if the received benefits will be worth the time and possible troubleshooting you may come across.